# How to capture onstop in marquee

Tags: javascript, marquee

I wrote this code in ASP.Net but it doesn't work, `onmouseout.stop()` doesn't work.

```
<marquee behavior="mouse" direction="up" onmouseover="this.start();" onmouseout="this.stop();">
    <list of body>
</marquee>
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is working

```
<marquee onmouseover="this.setAttribute('scrollamount', 0, 0);" onmouseout="this.setAttribute('scrollamount', 6, 0);">
my text here
</marquee>
```